# Parameter can't pass using ajax in Cross Domain

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain

I have used cross domain to call one domain to another as below ,

My ajax call from mvc project as done below,

```
var tableparameter = '{TableName: "' + $("#tableOneTableName").val() + '" }';
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/onchangetableone",
            data: tableparameter,
            success: function (response) {
               alert("hi");
            }
});
```

Then i added below code in web.config file within web api project as below,

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

Then i written action as below,

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/ajaxapi/onchangetableone")]
public List<DropDownListValuesForQuery> OnChangeTableOne(TableNameFormCustomFilters TableParameter)
{
        CaseModel query = new CaseModel();
        List<DropDownListValuesForQuery> listValues = new List<DropDownListValuesForQuery>();
        listValues = query.GetColumnNames(TableParameter.TableName);
        return listValues;
}
```

And list values as below,

```
public class TableNameFormCustomFilters
{
        public int TableName { get; set; }
}
```

Here i can access the webapi source using cross domain but the parameter value not come from script. Please give your suggestion.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Change your Js code var tableparameter = {"TableName": $("#tableOneTableName").val() };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your javascript obj little bit ,

```
    var TableParameter =
                {
                    TableName: $("#tableOneTableName").val()
                };
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/onchangetableone",
        data: TableParameter ,
        success: function (response) {
           alert("hi");
        }
  });
```

' TableParameter ' must be same as model parameter

Comment: Thanks , Happy Coding .

Answer (score 1):

Check below code :

```js
var TableParameter = { "TableName": $("#tableOneTableName").val() }; 

$.ajax(
{
url: 'http://localhost:55016/api/ajaxapi/onchangetableone/',
     type: "POST",
     async: false,
     contentType: "application/json;",
     data: JSON.stringify(TableParameter),
     success: function (result) {
     alert("hi");
 }
});
```

Cheers !!